# Odd bug with DataMapper, Mutexes, and Threads?

Tags: ruby, multithreading, concurrency, locking, datamapper

I have a database full of URLs that I need to test HTTP response time for on a regular basis.  I want to have many worker threads combing the database at all times for a URL that hasn't been tested recently, and if it finds one, test it.

Of course, this could cause multiple threads to snag the same URL from the database.  I don't want this.  So, I'm trying to use Mutexes to prevent this from happening.  I realize there are other options at the database level (optimistic locking, pessimistic locking), but I'd at least prefer to figure out why this isn't working.

Take a look at this test code I wrote:

```
threads = []
mutex = Mutex.new

50.times do |i|
  threads << Thread.new do
    while true do 
      url = nil

      mutex.synchronize do
        url = URL.first(:locked_for_testing => false, :times_tested.lt => 150)
        if url
          url.locked_for_testing = true
          url.save 
        end
      end

      if url
        # simulate testing the url
        sleep 1

        url.times_tested += 1
        url.save

        mutex.synchronize do
          url.locked_for_testing = false
          url.save
        end
      end
    end

    sleep 1
  end
end

threads.each { |t| t.join }
```

Of course there is no real URL testing here.  But what *should* happen is at the end of the day, each URL should end up with "times_tested" equal to 150, right?

(I'm basically just trying to make sure the mutexes and worker-thread mentality are working)

But each time I run it, a few odd URLs here and there end up with times_tested equal to a much lower number, say, 37, and locked_for_testing frozen on "true"

Now as far as I can tell from my code, if any URL gets locked, it will *have* to unlock.  So I don't understand how some URLs are ending up "frozen" like that.

There are no exceptions and I've tried adding begin/ensure but it didn't do anything.

Any ideas?

Comment: There is an unsynchronized url.save in there, that will cause problems. Also this does not seem like something that will benefit from the use of threads.

Comment: @pguardiario can you explain how the unsynchronized save causes problems? My logic is that nothing else should be touching that URL because it is already locked at that point. Also, this does benefit from threads because net connections are slow, so one computer can test many urls simultaneously.

Comment: Yes but the threads share a database connection. Database operations should always be synchronized since there's no reason for them not to be.

Comment: You're probably exhausting the connection pool

Comment: @FrederickCheung can you elaborate - I don't understand

Comment: Datamapper hands out connections from a fixed size pool. If a thread can't get a connection (because the pool is empty) then it will eventually give up. You could test whether this is the cause by decreasing the number of threads known. I'm not very familiar with data mapper's pooling

Comment: @FrederickCheung wouldn't an exception be raised if this is what was happening?

Comment: By default exceptions raised in other threads are swallowed silently and reraised when you call `t.join`, which in your code sample might never happen since the threads loop indefinitely (so your main thread will be blocked on the first call to t.join.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use a Queue, and a master to pull what you want.  if you have a single master you control what's getting accessed.  This isn't perfect but it's not going to blow up because of concurrency, remember if you aren't locking the database a mutex doesn't really help you is something else accesses the db.

code completely untested

```
require 'thread'
queue = Queue.new
keep_running = true

# trap cntrl_c or something to reset keep_running
master = Thread.new do 
  while keep_running
    # check if we need some work to do
    if queue.size == 0
      urls = URL.all(:times_tested.lt => 150)
      urls.each do |u|
        queue << u.id
      end
      # keep from spinning the queue
      sleep(0.1)
    end
  end
end
workers = []
50.times do
  workers << Thread.new do
    while keep_running
      # get an id
      id = queue.shift
      url = URL.get(id)
      #do something with the url
      url.save
      sleep(0.1)
    end
  end
end
workers.each do |w|
  w.join
end
```